# Find length of varchar(max) column

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am trying to find the length of string columns specified in a table.

I do this with the help of `CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH` from `infomation_schema.columns`.

However, for `varchar(max)` it returns -1. I was wondering if I should return the maximum allowed length whenever `varchar(max)`, `nvarchar(max)`, etc columns are present in the table?

Comment: information_schema.columns is theoretical length for varchar, nvarchar columns. Not actual. A (max) column can be 0 to 2000000000 bytes: you can't base any calculations on this. 10 varchar columns each of 100 length may take 0 or 1000 bytes: still a wild variation

Comment: Are you trying to find the maximum possible length of a string in a column, or the length of the longest string in a column? You can treat `varchar(max)` as unlimited (to a sensible extent).

Comment: IIRC, `nvarchar(MAX)` is equivalent to the legacy `ntext` type, correct? That means it's treated differently as far as storage in row is concerned than would be `nvarchar(4000)`. Which, I believe is the largest value before `nvarchar(MAX)`.

Comment: I am trying to find the maximum possible length allowed in the column.

Comment: Then your answer is `2000000000` as @gbn stated.

Comment: Looks like that. Basically I was trying to find the substring based on the length of the column to avoid error while inserting data in a table. But I guess it doesn't make sense to find a substring in case of MAX column. 

Please comment.

Comment: @kanu that's how I would treat it as well. Just treat -1 as unlimited. BTW StackOverflow Tip: if you use `@username` in your comment, then that person gets notified of a comment and doesn't have to keep checking back (I just happened to have the page open from earlier).

Comment: varchar(max) - max indicates that the maximum storage size is 2^31-1 bytes (2147483647). Some people said 2000000000, which is about 140MB smaller than the real maximum length value. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176089.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the maximum length of a varchar(max) or nvarchar(max) column is not unlimited. 
The storage limit is 2GB (2^31 -1 bytes). 
It behaves as a regular varchar/nvarchar column when the data is less than 8kb. Then when the data for a individual row is greater than 8kb, it is stored as a large-object text/ntext value. You can think of it like a wrapper for the 2 data types.

However, the maximum character length **is not** `2000000000`. 
It is 2147483645 for a varchar(max) column and 1073741822 for a nvarchar(max) column. 
This is because an nvarchar has 2 bytes per character and a varchar has 1 byte per character and 2 bytes are needed to store the data length of a variable column.

I don't think any extra metadata is subtracted from the 2GB limit but I will comment tomorrow if I find anything else.